# Connect to SQL Server instance AWS Glue

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, aws-glue

I need to connect to SQL Server from Glue via JDBC, can someone advise how to specify instance name in JDBC.

The following connection string works for the default instance however I need to pass instance name to it.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://xxx-cluster.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;databaseName=employee
```

Comment: Are you encountering any error?

Comment: Is your sql server present in RDS or on prem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct as your endpoint contains the instance address only.
What problem you are facing?

Comment: this was successful as per below. jdbc:sqlserver://xxx-cluster.cluster-xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com\fff_test:1433;databaseName=employee. however it is not importing any tables when i run crawlers.