# AWS Glue – Data connections – SQL server InstanceName ignored in JDBC URL

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-glue

Does anybody know what is the correct correct JDBC syntax to connect AWS GLUE to and SQL Server instance (on premise, so outside of RDS) ?

In the following AWS GLUE Data connection JDBC URL, the instancename “**\INSTANCENAME**” is ignored : jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.1**\INSTANCENAME**:1433/DBNAME

**In the connexion string above :**

- Server IP Address is : 192.168.0.1
- SQL Server instanceName is : INSTANCENAME
- Connexion port is : 1433
- Database name is : DBNAME

**HINTS :**

- Athena's Lambda function is able to connect to the same server using the following JDBC connection String : sqlserver ://jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.1;instanceName=**INSTANCENAME**;databaseName=DBNAME;encrypt=false
- I'm able to connect to the same server using another user on the same SQL Server’s default (blank) instance, even adding \INSTANCENAME to the JDBC URL. This is how I was able to determine that “**\INSTANCENAME**” is ignored, but also, that there is no network issue.
- The Cloudwatch logs says that the Login / password / URL are false, because user AWS_Athena doesn’t exist on default (blank) instance, only on instance INSTANCENAME.

**Attempted & failed solutions :**

- I've tried replacing \ by \\ but this didn't change anything. Perhaps an escape character is needed ?
- Also tried adding "instanceName=**INSTANCENAME**" to the connexion string
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63180419/connect-to-sql-server-instance-aws-glue](https://stackoverflow.com) not working.

Comment: Combining instance name and port is always a mistake, it's either OR. For instance name you need to open the browser port 1434 i think. I prefer to avoid instance name altogether and always use port.

Comment: Thanks  siggemannen. VPC level :
 - UDP port 1434 is already open
 - TCP port 1433 is also open 
 - Glue endpoint is already created.
I'm pretty sure that it's not a network issue.

Comment: what error are you getting if you remove the instancename thing altogether

Comment: AWS Glue runs your ETL jobs in a Spark or Ray engine seperate from your other resources. Have you applied an IAM Role and Security Group(s) to it that will allow it to access your SQL Server instance? Given that 192.168.0.0/16 is a non-routable network how does your Athena Lambda function connect to your on-premise SQL Server?

Comment: @siggemannen, I get the same result when removing the instancename altogether.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Yes. When testing connection, Cloudwatch sends me messages containing Connection ID : "ClientConnectionId:ce1de628-5854-4e34-9015-fe306499556d". So I know that glue is able to communicate with SQL server, just not with the correct instancename.

Comment: Then the port doesn't match? Check sql server config

Comment: It's the InstanceName that doesn't match. Port is ok.